# Open Source Search Engine

Tags: c++, search-engine

I'm learning search technology and reading the paper about Google prototype.

Is there an open source search engine written in C++ that is easy to read?

Comment: Any particular language/complexity?
You can get a list of some here:
http://www.searchtools.com/tools/tools-opensource.html

Comment: Interestingly, you didn't use Google to search for this.  Why didn't you use google to search for an open source search engine?

Answer (score 9):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org) is probably the first place to look.

Comment: There is also a port of Lucene to PHP: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html (At least I think it's a full port and not a wrapper).

Comment: Lucene is Java, not C++

Comment: There's clucene http://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene/

Answer (score 6):

[Xapian](http://xapian.org/) is a popular open-source search engine written in C++

Answer (score 5):

here is port for the Lucene search engine in Perl, which will give you access to the c++ API

with tutorial

[Lucene](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lucene)

Answer (score 3):

[clucene](http://clucene.sourceforge.net/)

Since i know nothing about java,I found clucene, it's a c++ port of lucene.